# Linking CSS/JS in Laravel's Blade Templates

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel-5

I noticed earlier that when I added parameters to my routes, this broke my views as it seemed to change the links to my CSS and JS files. After hours of trying to get the HTML package working in Laravel 5.1, I finally gave up and threw in the towel due to Composer issues.

I opted to just take the simple route and go back to linking them directly, however I am now struggling to get even this to work.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ public_path() }}/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ public_path() }}/assets/css/metismenu.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ public_path() }}/assets/css/sb-admin-2.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ public_path() }}/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ public_path() }}/assets/css/datatables.bootstrap.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ public_path() }}/assets/css/datatables.responsive.css">
```

Rather than linking to the local file, its appending the entire string to my base URL and trying to link to that which is obviously wrong.

Current Link:

```
http://domain.com/home/roster/laravel/public/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Correct Link:

```
http://domain.com/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Just linking to "/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" works fine until I add Route parameters. What can I do to get these links working short of hard coding the entire URL?

Comment: Whoever posted the answer, then edited and then deleted it, the edit worked great. If you would like to add it back, I will accept. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that, I found a new solution so I deleted it and trying to add a new one :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very rare. I am working with L5.1 and looks good together with HTML package. Just to keep in mind. Require the following package:

```
"illuminate/html": "~5.0@dev"
```

Then run `composer update`. After the package is installed, edit `config/app.php` adding the provider:

```
 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

And facade:

```
'HTML' => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'
```

Now, lets see some solutions to show your assets links:

- Using html facade

  ```
  {!! HTML::style('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') !!}
  ```
- Using raw code calling `url()` function:

  ```
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
  ```
- Using raw code calling `URL` facade:

  ```
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
  ```

> As a note, do not use `public_path`() because it returns an absolute directory path like  `/var/www/html/laravel` instead an url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<link href="<?php echo URL::asset('css/app.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I believe this will fix your problem

Another solution:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('/') }}/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: As mentioned, I spent hours trying to get the HTML package working without any luck due to composer. It has been removed in Laravel 5.1 and only some community managed package is still available but apparently does not work for me.

Comment: See updates, I think both of these will work for you.